# Blues E scale on guitar

Tags: guitar, scales, blues

I am currently learning the guitar, particularly solo-ing, and teaching myself by figuring out the Blues scale in various keys. At the moment I'm looking at the key of E.

The way I understand it (may be incorrect) the Blues scale is based on this formula:

`1 b3 4 b5 5 b7`

That should mean the Blues scale in key of E becomes:

`E Gb A Bb B Db`

However, in a lot of places, not the least being the very highly-rated [Guitarist's Reference](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.nroid.guitaristsreference) app on Android, the scale is said to be:

`E G A Bb B D`

Being a newbie I'm struggling to find the reasoning behind this, and how it applies to other keys. Any pointers would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

That notation (`1 b3 4 b5 5 b7`) is used to relate a scale to the major (ionian) scale. It shows which scale degrees should be flattened or sharpened (and by how much) relative to the major scale.

So, you should start with E *major* scale, not E minor or E phrygian (natural notes from E to E: `E F G A B C D`). E major scale is of course `1=E 2=F# 3=G# 4=A 5=B 6=C# 7=D#`. Because these are the notes that the famous `W W H W W W H` (W=whole, H=half, two frets and one fret on guitar respectively) formula produces when you start with E.

If you apply the formula `1 b3 4 b5 5 b7`, you end up with `E G A Bb B D`, which is what you found. Because the flats in b3 and b7 cancels the sharps of G# and D#.

Comment: AHA!!! Correct formula, wrong starting point! Thank you, that cleared it up perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

Surprisingly, this question hasn't spawned an answer regarding the *other* blues scale - the major blues. Notes constituting this are E, F#, G, G#, B, C#. In E major. Not quite as much used as the *minor* blues, as it essentially works only over *major* chords, whereas the minor blues works over major, seventh *and* minor chords.

Your translation of notes for the *minor* blues scale is skewed - they are in fact E, G, A, Bb, B, D, and can be played for just about any blues in E, but it's good to also be able to throw in those other notes previously mentioned in this answer.

Comment: It works over major chords AND seventh chords. It doesn't need the 7th to work over 7th chords (as long as you don't add a major 7th). It is often used over the I7 chord, and over the IV7 chord one could switch to the (minor) blues scale.

Comment: @MattL. - good point, although care needs to be taken with the 6th note (C# here) as it'll clash with that b7 - unless a 13th is intended.